# What is a good word for foods that have pronounced and pleasant amount of salt?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

As far as I understand if you say food is salty it usually means an excessive amount of salt is added to the food. I also think 'savoury' refers to neither sweet nor sour foods and not specifically to saltiness.

What is the correct adjective or adjective clause for foods like cheese,  potato chips, and tortillas? Or a piece of pizza that has more than normal salt but still in a pleasant way?

Comment: It's a bit of a "Goldilocks" situation (Daddy Bear's porridge is too hot, Mummy Bear's is too cold, but Baby Bear's porridge is ***just right*** for Goldilocks). I don't think there's an English word for *well-salted, but **not too salty***. No more so than *well-sweetened, but **not too sickly-sweet*** (for which there's ***huge*** variability between different people's personal preferences). Generic ***seasoned to perfection*** is a common expression, though.

Comment: Snacks like potato chips/crisps are salted by definition (except the kind that come with a packet of salt so you can add your own!), so we don't really need a special adjective. You can buy 'lightly salted' ones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - my wife has pre-hypertension, and my blood pressure is on the high side of normal, so for about 25 years we have not used salt in cooking or at the table, and carefully examine the salt contents of prepared foods we buy, and try to buy low- or no-salt varieties. We firmly believe that a healthy balanced diet with no ultra-processed foods has more than enough salt for our needs. The result for me has been that many things now taste unpleasantly salty.

Comment: @KateBunting - Smiths Crisps . . . the blue ones are very salty!!  I didn't know these still existed, now made by Walkers aparently (same company as Lays in the US).

Comment: I find 'salted caramel' tastes vile.

Comment: Yes, I try to limit my salt intake and find the ones that aren't 'lightly salted' unpleasantly salty.

Comment: [Nothing to do with ELL, but] Smiths & Walkers were once separate companies, but all became part of Nabisco. Smiths, who had until the 70s been the largest brand by far [95% in the 40s], were losing sales on crisps to Golden Wonder, whilst retaining the overall 'snacks' market. Smiths just re-labelled a lot of Smiths to Walkers, but unfortunately went with their method & flavours. You can still get Smiths with a blue bag [if you look really hard]. Unfortunately, I've always found Walkers to be almost inedible, Smiths were far better. The nation lost a treasure in that shift.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possibilities I can think of, but no single word adjective comes to mind:

**well-seasoned**

This means a generous amount of salt, pepper, and spices. It wouldn't generally be used for desserts or anything predominantly sweet. You could use **very** before this to intensify the meaning.

> It was a well-seasoned steak.
>
> These tortilla chips are very well seasoned.

**very flavourful**

This is much more general and could apply to almost any tasty food. Not specifically about salt, rather "filled with flavour".

> These crisps (potato chips) are very flavourful.
>
> That was a very flavourful soup.

**nice and salty** (UK colloquial/informal expression)

It means on the salty side of the spectrum, but still pleasant (nice).

> I love anchovy pizza. It's nice and salty.

Comment: Would agree with "nice and salty" as well here in Canada. A good hendiadys solves many a vocabulary problem :)

Comment: I like the third one, the other two are simply irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd IMO, "well-seasoned" is the most correct answer. I don't see why you think it's irrelevant.